# Running powershell script in Webjob

Tags: powershell, azure, webjob

I am running below powershell script in Azure Webjob to conenct to Storage account and upload a file

```
Write-Output "Getting Azure storage context..."
   $storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext  -StorageAccountName "awemigcitest" -StorageAccountKey "xx+74Z81YJf373p88Emp2jKidMZ8b4/+UTLJT4Rvgqrc8IedRxkg=="

$ProgressPreference="SilentlyContinue"
   Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob $azureBlobStorageFileName -File $tempFilename -Container $MigrationReportsContainerName -Context $storageContext  -Force
   Write-Output "Copied HTML file to Azure blob storage."
```

But getting below error. Any idea on this?

> New-AzureStorageContext : The Win32 internal error "The handle is invalid" 0x6 
>   [09/30/2017 06:41:20 > 4db5e9: ERR ] occurred while setting character attributes for the console output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The commands you're using seems ok, it works for me both on local and Azure WebJob. Please check if your scripts can work on local. Besides, if possible, you can try to create a new WebJob to run your script, and check if it can work fine.

```
Write-Output "Getting Azure storage context..."
   $storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext  -StorageAccountName "{account_name}" -StorageAccountKey "{account_key}"

$ProgressPreference="SilentlyContinue"
   Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob 'source.txt' -File 'D:\home\data\jobs\continuous\FileIn.txt' -Container 'mycontainer' -Context $storageContext  -Force
   Write-Output "Copied HTML file to Azure blob storage."
```

***WebJob Logs***

[image]

Note: I use [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to access site folder and create `FileIn.txt`.